# How to use Checkboxes for PreferenceActivity class in android

Tags: android, synchronization, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I have MenuSettings in which I have PreferenceActivity class. In PreferenceActivity I have displayed checkboxPreference like below.

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<PreferenceCategory
 android:title="Options">

 <CheckBoxPreference
   android:key="pref_opt1"
   android:title="Option 1"
   android:summary="Tick to set this option"
   android:defaultValue="true"
   />
<CheckBoxPreference
   android:key="pref_opt2"
   android:title="Option 2"
   android:summary="Tick to set this option"
   android:defaultValue="true"
   />
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to use checkboxes to perform function for synchronization that I have build, But Please can any body let me know how to use checkboxes in PreferenceActivity. Is there any need to create another Activity? or we can perform function in same PreferenceActivity?

```
 here is my PreferenceActivity:

 public class SharedPref extends PreferenceActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sharedpref);


}
// StorePreference method{
                         }
   // readPreferences method{
                            }
}
```

Comment: Check this link: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/

Comment: @shree202, yes this is exactly what I want. Thank you so much. You save my day.

Comment: You're welcome friend.